# Show a series of functions is discontinuous at a point

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

I have a series of functions which converges to an integrable function. I need to show that this function is discontinuous at every point . For starters (because of the way it's defined) I'm just considering every rational number and it's quite obvious for each of these points there are exactly two terms in the series that are discontinuous. The essence of my question is this:
Does having discontinuous terms in your series of functions imply discontinuity of the sum?

EDIT: I'm talking about Lebesgue integrable of course

Comment: By integrable,  I hope you are meaning Lebesgue integrable, since a function needs to be continuous on all but a measure 0 set to be Riemann integrable...

Comment: Yeah I definitely mean Lebesgue integrable, I'll make a mention of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R(i)$ for $i=1,2,\cdots$ be an enumeration of the rationals on $[0,1]$. Define $f_0(x)=1$ if $x$ is irrational and $0$ otherwise. Define $f_i(x)=1$ when $x=R(i)$ and 0 otherwise. Also, define:

$$S_n(x):=\sum_{i=0}^n f_i(x)$$

Then

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n(x)=1$$

which is very much a continuous function.

Comment: Thanks, I can see now that it won't be true in general